# Python: preg_replace function analog

Tags: php, python, preg-replace

I have a litle expression in PHP:

```
  $search = array("'<(script|noscript|style|noindex)[^>]*?>.*?</(script|noscript|style|noindex)>'si",
    "'<\!--.*?-->'si",
    "'<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>'si",
    "'([\r\n])[\s]+'");

$replace = array ("",
  "",
  " ", 
  "\\1 ");

  $text = preg_replace($search, $replace, $this->pageHtml);
```

How i did run this on python? `re.sub`?

Comment: Yes, `re.sub`. Did you try it?

Comment: @bereal ok, how did i set multiple patterns and replacements to `re.sub`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a special call for that, but why not using '|' as described e.g. [here](http://emilics.com/blog/article/multi_replace.html)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [@bereal commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331591/python-preg-replace-function-analog#comment21651285_15331591) use the Regular Expression module [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub).

Here's a simple example

Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([^A-Z])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', 'camelCase').lower()
'camel_case'
```

And just for kicks here's it on PHP too:

```php
<?php
echo strtolower(preg_replace('/([^A-Z])([A-Z])/', '$1_$2', 'camelCase'));
// prints camel_case
```